# separate output of input() function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to separate the output from the input function in Python?

For example, let's say that we want to insert a number and name.

```
input('Give number and name:')
Give number and name:14,John
'14,John'
```

We get `'14,John'`. Is there a way to take `'14','John'`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
user_input = input("Please write a number then a name, separated by a comma: ")

number, name = user_input.split(", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.split()`

```
>>> input('Give number and name: ').split(',')
Give number and name: 14,John
['14','John']
```

or

```
>>> number, name = input('Give number and name: ').split(',')
Give number and name: 14,John
>>> number
'14'
>>> name
'John'
```

Note that they are both `strings`